# Discovery Channel movie about a rover entering an organic spaceship, activating a green light that causes black spheres to appear on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This isn't something I remember well, but I'll do my best to describe it.

I watched this around 2013-2014, on Discovery Channel. It was some kind of movie or TV show about a hypothetical situation where an alien space ship shows up in orbit around the Earth. A rover is sent into the ship to analyze it and find out what the inhabitants look like.

The ship's interior was black, with a lot of fragmented sharp edges and a lot of green glowing lights everywhere.

At some point the rover activates a glowing green light, like a generator or something (this part is vague in my memory) and through some kind of series of events reveals that the ship isn't piloted by aliens, it *is* the alien. Activating this light causes a vast amount of black spheres to appear on Earth that then slowly break apart into smaller and smaller spheres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it could be *Alien Encounters*, a docudrama aired on Discovery Science between 2012 and 2014.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2257878/):

> Alien Encounters is a docudrama revolving around an alien space ship that was spotted traveling to earth for unknown reasons. Throughout the episodes, we are presented with the fictitious but all too familiar documentary style scientific details of our technologies, alien technologies and how this encounter develops.

More precisely...

**The ship's interior was black, with a lot of fragmented sharp edges and a lot of green glowing lights everywhere.**

The video below has a couple of "robot exploring the ship" scenes, with a glowing green structure-thingy (at 0'20 and 1'48). Here's [a screenshot with the black sharp edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qugDA.png).

**Some kind of series of events reveals that the ship isn't piloted by aliens, it *is* the alien.**

The series apparently focuses on the relationships between biology and technology; especially, the ship is rumored to be the combination of both, as pointed out by these two quotes from the video above:

> Signs of life... I think it's very likely that an advanced civilization would combine the advantages of machines with the advantages of biological systems. *(timestamp: 0'32)*

...

> Could this alien species have gone from the same transformation? Did this great living machine have organic origins? *(timestamp: 2'55)*

**Activating this light causes a vast amount of black spheres to appear on Earth that then slowly break apart into smaller and smaller spheres.**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Encounters_(TV_series)) mentions, in the second season:

> Episode 1: Alien spacecrafts deposit thousands of pods on the Earth's surface.
>
> Episode 2: Humans learn to coexist with the ever shrinking multiplying alien pods.

And here's a picture of the spheres:

[image: Black spiky spheres]

---

I found it by Googling `discovery channel alien spaceship orbiting earth`, which returned [*Alien Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Planet). It wasn't the one, but as it was labeled "docufiction", I searched for `discovery channel docu fiction alien ship`, and *Alien Encounters* was in the top three results.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you!

Comment: @SydneySleeper you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :)