# 2000s movie where mysterious black alien spheres surround the Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, hard-sci-fi

Can you please help me find the title of this movie, from about 2010, in which hundreds of black alien spheres position themselves evenly around the planet.  The humans are unsurprisingly curious, worried, and defensive.  Most of the movie follows how people react to the presence of these structures, with building tension.  The military even tries to blow some of the spheres out of the sky using nuclear missiles, but they have no effect.  It's not a high-budget blockbuster, I don't think it had any A-list Hollywood actors, and was possibly from a Canadian filmhouse.

In the end,

> an asteroid or meteor shower that would have obliterated life on Earth is stopped by the spheres, and they spheres depart, without any contact with the aliens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're referring to *[The Beyond](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5723416/)* (2017). It's a bit more recent than you suggested, but it matches your description in respect to the black spheres surrounding the Earth and the meteor shower near the end.

> Set in 2019, The Beyond chronicles the groundbreaking mission which sent astronauts – modified with advanced robotics, through a newly discovered wormhole known as the Void. When the mission returns unexpectedly, the space agency races to discover what the astronauts encountered on their first of its kind interstellar space journey.

Comment: Wow. This looks dreadful.

Comment: @Valorum It's *Beyond* dreadful!

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Not as bad as StarCrash though.